# Compress a table into three columns without using a pivot table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table that I want to condense into a chart. I am concerned about using a pivot table because ultimately I want to export the data. [Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1umeinJLZB7QKIflB_fLpzwueU_Ydx1txA59idMUVxYs/edit?usp=sharing) looks like this:

[image: data]

This is one tab of the master document which has ~26 tabs (the full year)

I would like the result to look like this:

[image: Example]

I tried some basic arrays but could not grab all the data (i.e. only two variables, not three). I also tried the query function but I am not familiar enough with it to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flattening a two-dimensional array without a pivot table is kind of a pain in Sheets. In your situation, it looks like the number of columns is not going to change very often, so it's reasonable to use a formula that has them hard-coded in:

```
=sort({
filter({A4:A, iferror(A4:A/0, C3), C4:C}, len(C4:C)); 
filter({A4:A, iferror(A4:A/0, D3), D4:D}, len(D4:D)); 
filter({A4:A, iferror(A4:A/0, E3), E4:E}, len(E4:E));
filter({A4:A, iferror(A4:A/0, F3), F4:F}, len(F4:F));
filter({A4:A, iferror(A4:A/0, G3), G4:G}, len(G4:G));
filter({A4:A, iferror(A4:A/0, H3), H4:H}, len(H4:H));
filter({A4:A, iferror(A4:A/0, I3), I4:I}, len(I4:I))
}, 1, true)
```

It helps to remember that formulas can have linebreaks (Ctrl-Enter) and that the formula window is expandable.

#### Explanation

- `{A4:A, iferror(A4:A/0, C3), C4:C}` forms a three-column array where the first column is the date, the third is time, and the 2nd column is the person's name repeated (the division-by-zero is a trick to make this repetition happen).
- `len(C4:C)` is the filter condition: only take the rows with time entered
- the results of `filter` are stacked vertically (semicolon) and then sorted by date (1st column), in ascending order (true).